# MSAL.JS 1.2.0 Login Redirect - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL '' from frame URL ''

Tags: javascript, angular, safari, active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We're currently migrating our SPA's (Angular 8) authentication library from ADAL.js 1.0.16 to **MSAL.js 1.2.0**.

The authentication process works fine with the newest MSAL version on Chrome v76.0.3809.100 and Firefox v68.0.2.

However, on **Safari** v13.0.4 we have two scenarios, depending on the state of the "Prevent cross-site tracking" property:

**- Checked:** the application works fine.

**- Unchecked:** the login process stops on the redirect, and we get the error message below:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'https://myapplication.com/' from frame with URL 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=token&scope=...'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation' flag is not set.

Inspecting the iFrame, the sandbox tag provides two values: allow-scripts and allow-same-origin, and not the allow-top-navigation as expected on the error message.

Additionally, there is another issue associated with MSAL and Safari, that blocks the acquire token process, which is solved unchecking the "Prevent cross-site tracking" property:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/Known-issue-on-Safari

The bottom line is, just turning off the "Prevent cross-site tracking" is not an option once that we also faced the error when acquiring a token silently.

I'd appreciate getting some directions on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: MSAL documentation says to catch the acquireTokenSilent, but this "Unsafe JavaScript" comes from the browser and not from the application; so it is not catchable.